# Multiple filtering on Django Prefetch

Tags: django

Based on my codebase:

```py
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class District(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Park(models.Model):
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parks")

class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    plant_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    park = models.ForeignKey(Park, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="plants")

def plants_of_type_in_park(plant_type, park):
    return park.plants.filter(plant_type=plant_type)

def generate_garden_report():
    report_data = {}
    plant_types = ["rose", "tulip", "daisy", ...etc]
    districts = District.objects.all()
    districts = districts.prefetch_related("parks", "parks__plants")
    for dist in districts.all():
        for park in districts.parks.all():
            for plant in plant_types:
                report_data[dist.city.name][plant] += plants_of_type_in_park(plant, park).count()
    return report_data
```

My objective is to optimize the `generate_garden_report` function using prefetching. I have added `districts.prefetch_related("parks", "parks__plants")`. However, since `plants_of_type_in_park` uses a filter, it triggers another query. My approach was to prefetch each filter:

```py
districts = districts.prefetch_related("parks", "parks__plants")
for plant in plant_types:
    districts = districts.prefetch_related(Prefetch("parks_plants", queryset=Plant.objects.filter(plant_type=plant)))
```

But, as `parks_plants` can only be assigned once, I can't create multiple filters for this. My goal is to prefetch everything needed with minimal impact on the `plants_of_type_in_park` function, as it is used elsewhere in the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further enhance performance, you can annotate the parks with counts of each plant type and then access them directly.

Here's an example:

```py
def generate_garden_report():
    report_data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    plant_types = ["rose", "tulip", "daisy"]
    districts = District.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'parks',
            queryset=Park.objects.annotate(
                **{plant_type: Count('plants', filter=Q(plants__plant_type=plant_type)) for plant_type in plant_types}
            )
        )
    )

    for dist in districts:
        city_name = dist.city.name
        for park in dist.parks.all():
            for plant_type in plant_types:
                report_data[city_name][plant_type] += getattr(park, plant_type, 0)
    return report_data
```